# Keep header row in each page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm writting a SSRS 2008 report using 1 tablix and 2 Row groups, I've flagged the page break options for the parent group and Rows headers options in the tablix properties.

The page break is working fine, but I can't show the header en each page. I was tried to many ways with unsucessfully result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a page header to appear on every page, there is an option to add page header sections in SSRS: on the design surface, right-click the report, point to Insert, and then click Header or Footer.

More information about page headers and footers in SSRS can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159677%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks!! but I don't have page header in my report, just a row header and I want to repeat them in every page

Comment: Finally I could repeat the row header in each page of the report with groups only, Thanks for all your help...  I want to share my solution if someone need to do something similar...                                                          I setup the following properties in the static first column  FixedData = true,  KeepWithGroup  = After amd Repearonnewpage = true

Answer (score 1):

There's two sets of properties and both have to be set... one on the tablix itself (repeat on new page), then just above the group list there's a button on the right to go into advanced mode. That shows you some hidden (Static) groups, and once you select those they also have properties to repeat on new page that have to be set.

Comment: I tried to set up those properties in all static groups but still doesn't working

Comment: Perhaps you could post a screenshot of your design surface and the relevant properties so we can confirm it? With that said, there are some rare cases (usually on more complicated tablixes where I've added and removed a lot of groups and rows) that the settings won't be honored, and the only way to enforce them is to create a new tablix and set it up properly on the first go. I don't think this applies to you, but it's something to keep in mind.